# How do I safely change the "lib" directory name in Flutter Android Studio project?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I've created a Flutter app in Android Studio and I want to change the name of the "lib" directory (in which Dart source files reside) to "src".

However when I do that, the import to 'package:/main.dart' fails. How can I change that?

I changed the path in the .iml file, and the project compiles and runs, but this test file still shows an error.

Comment: You could depend from the lib/main.dart file to the src folder.

Answer (score 5):

This name is hardcoded and there is no way to change it.
The whole `pub` package system depends on that directory name.

There is also a convention that tools like the analyzer support code in `lib/src` being considered package-private when not exported by files in other directories in `lib/`.

Comment: I'm making apps (not libraries or frameworks). Is there another hard-coded directory name I'm unaware of?

Comment: I'm pretty there is just `lib/` that's fixed.